# What's the significance of the dog on Mars?

Tags: ad-astra

In a very short scene on Mars [timestamp approx 55:45], you can see something resembling a dog.
What breed is it? To me it looks like German Shepherd.
What is its significance?

[image]

Zoomed gif…

[image]

Comment: That really looks like a [German Shepherd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_Shepherd)

Comment: btw, you can do screenshots in VLC with Ctrl/S [Win] or Cmd/Opt/S [Mac] - rather than having to screenshot the viewport, borders, interface & all. I replaced this one with a cleaner copy.

Comment: I made a zoomed gif too - it's not really any clearer but you get a better all-round look at the dog. Does look like a German Shepherd to me too, but no clue what significance, if any.

Comment: Thanks to all of you!